# CSS list question

Tags: html, css, xhtml

Can anyone help with this CSS problem.  I need NavDropDown to get wider when any NavLevel2 text gets longer than 200px.  There should be no text wrap in the list items and NavLevel1 should always be 200px wide.

```
<div id="Nav">
    <ul>
        <li class="NavLevel1" style="width: 200px; border: 1px solid Black;"><a><span>Level 1.1</span></a>
            <ul id="NavDropDown" style="border: 1px solid Black;">
                <li class="NavLevel2"><a><span>Level 2.1.1 test to see if this will push the width out a little</span></a></li>
                <li class="NavLevel2"><a><span>Level 2.1.2</span></a></li>
                <li class="NavLevel2"><a><span>Level 2.1.3</span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: please add pictures of the current and expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted to hastily, just found my solution.

```
<div id="Nav">
    <ul>
        <li class="NavLevel1" style="width: 200px; border: 1px solid Black;"><a><span>Level 1.1</span></a>
            <ul id="NavDropDown" style="border: 1px solid Black; position:absolute;">
                <li class="NavLevel2" style="white-space: nowrap;"><a><span>Level 2.1.1 test to see if this will push the width out a little</span></a></li>
                <li class="NavLevel2"><a><span>Level 2.1.2</span></a></li>
                <li class="NavLevel2"><a><span>Level 2.1.3</span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

change the `width` style to `min-width`.

Comment: If I do that NavLevel1 width extends across the whoel page.  It needs to stay 200px;

Comment: You could set a `max-width` as well.  Probably your best bet is to use `<nobr>` tags around the content in the `li` items that way the content is forced to have no breaks and will push the width wider.  Try that.